# Vertx OAuth2AuthHandler with multiple providers (Facebook, Google or any)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, vert.x

I'am trying to make Vertx http-server to authenticate user by one of several Auth providers by their choice, like FormBased, Facebook, Google or any other oAuth2 Provider on the same login page. Is it possible?

Now I have code with working only one oAuth2 provider. When I add second the system crush with error:

> Sep 21, 2018 7:54:36 PM io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase
>   SEVERE: Unexpected exception in route
>   io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: The code passed is incorrect
>   or expired.

Code with error:

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerOptions;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.net.JksOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Auth;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.providers.FacebookAuth;
import io.vertx.ext.auth.oauth2.providers.GithubAuth;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.OAuth2AuthHandler;
import sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {
    // you should never store these in code,
    // these are your github application credentials
    private static final String FB_CLIENT_ID = "xxx";
    private static final String FB_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxx";

    private static final String GH_CLIENT_ID = "yyy";
    private static final String GH_CLIENT_SECRET = "yyy";

    private static final String HOST_NAME = "dev.service.com";

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        OAuth2Auth ghAuthProvider = GithubAuth.create(vertx, GH_CLIENT_ID, GH_CLIENT_SECRET);
        OAuth2Auth fbAuthProvider = FacebookAuth.create(vertx, FB_CLIENT_ID, FB_CLIENT_SECRET);

        // create a oauth2 handler for GitHub
        OAuth2AuthHandler ghAuthHandler = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(ghAuthProvider, "https://" + HOST_NAME + "/callback");
        ghAuthHandler.addAuthority("profile");
        ghAuthHandler.setupCallback(router.get("/callback"));

        // create a oauth2 handler for Facebook
        OAuth2AuthHandler fbAuthHandler = OAuth2AuthHandler.create(fbAuthProvider, "https://" + HOST_NAME + "/callback")
                .extraParams(new JsonObject().put("scope", "email"))
                .setupCallback(router.route());

        // protect everything under /ghprotected
        router.route("/ghprotected/*").handler(ghAuthHandler);
        // mount some handler under the protected zone
        router.route("/ghprotected/somepage").handler(rc -> rc.response()
                .end("Welcome to the GH protected resource!"));

        // protect everything under /fbprotected
        router.route("/fbprotected/*").handler(fbAuthHandler);
        // mount some handler under the protected zone
        router.route("/fbprotected/somepage").handler(rc -> rc.response()
                .end("Welcome to the FB protected resource!"));

        router.get("/fbprotected").handler(ctx -> {
            ctx.response()
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
                    // .end(userInfo.encodePrettily());
                    .end("fb login handler");
        });

        // welcome page
        router.get("/").handler(ctx -> ctx.response()
                .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
                .end("Hello<br><a href=\"/ghprotected/somepage\">Protected by GitHub</a>" +
                        "<a href=\"/fbprotected/somepage\">Protected by FB</a>"));


        // Create http server with SSL and self signed certificate
        HttpServerOptions httpOpts = new HttpServerOptions();
        try {
            // Generate a self-signed key pair and certificate.
            KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            store.load(null, null);
            CertAndKeyGen keypair = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA1WithRSA", null);
            X500Name x500Name = new X500Name("localhost", "IT", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "unknown");
            keypair.generate(1024);
            PrivateKey privKey = keypair.getPrivateKey();
            X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
            chain[0] = keypair.getSelfCertificate(x500Name, new Date(), (long) 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
            store.setKeyEntry("selfsigned", privKey, "changeit".toCharArray(), chain);
            store.store(new FileOutputStream(".keystore"), "changeit".toCharArray());
            httpOpts.setKeyStoreOptions(new JksOptions().setPath(".keystore").setPassword("changeit"));
            httpOpts.setSsl(true);
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | NoSuchProviderException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException ex) {
            // Logger.getLogger(WebServerVerticle.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to generate a self-signed cert and other SSL configuration methods failed.", ex);
            // startFuture.fail(ex);
            System.out.println("error with ssl");
        }
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(httpOpts);

        server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(443);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I won't be able to help you solve, but you should make it clear which provider it was working with and then which provider you added which caused the script to begin failing.

Comment: If I leave only one Provider (ghAuthProvider or fbAuthProvider) it will work normally, but when I try to use both of them, one of them fail. In this case it's fbAuthProvider. I can't find any examples where shown how to use multiple auth providers to get access to private part of the service.

Comment: How can I switch between AuthProviders?

Comment: I have found my error. I used one callback URL for 2 different OAuth providers. Don't do that. ;) Use different callback urls for each auth provider. Now it's working great!